# Mocking a simple closed function returned from another function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function called `fnCreater` that creates another function:

```
const fnCreater = (page, extraCondition = false) => () => {
  if (extraCondition) return;
  ViewStore.setCurrentPage = page;
}
```

I want to be able to test whether the returned function is called:

```
describe('test', () => {
    it('should return a function', () => {
        const fn = fnCreater('CONFIGURATOR')
        expect(typeof fn).toBe('function')
    })

    it('should be able to execute the function from the closure', () => {
        const fn = fnCreater('CONFIGURATOR')
        // const spy = jest.spyOn(fn) // needs a 'module'
        fn();
        expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
})
```

I'm not too familiar with jest, but the test returns this error:

```
Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function anonymous]
```

I don't understand how to fix this, or why the error is stating a spy or mock is needed - spyOn needs an object and mock needs a module. The `fnCreater` function itself returns another function (`fn`), and I want to determine whether *that* closed function has been called. How can this be done?

Comment: `fnCreater` create a new function every time, so calling it and spying on returned function doesn't make sense. You would rather have to mock it to return a spy instead

Comment: can you demonstrate how this can be achieved? will it still run the `fnCreater` function, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Is this `fnCreater` function in a module?

Comment: By in a module, do you mean in a separate file? If so, then yes

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to test fnCreater or the code that calls it?

If you are testing fnCreater itself, you should not mock it.

I would suggest calling fnCreater, then call the returned Function and assert the proper page is set.

Comment: I want to test the function that fnCreater returns. I already tried calling the function returned from fnCreater, but the error in the brief occurred which said I need to mock or spy it

Comment: You don't need to assert the function was called if you are calling it directly in your test. Just call it and check the result is what you expect.